# Why do I get long delays when using LDTP (Cobra/PyATOM)

Tags: python, gui-testing

I trying to write GUI tests using the [Linux Desktop Testing Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Desktop_Testing_Project) (ldtp).  It seems to work, except that I get long delays at unpredictable times.

For example, when I try:

```
import os
from ldtp import *
from ldtputils import *
from time import sleep

launchapp('gedit')
waittillguiexist('*-gedit')
ldtp.selectmenuitem ('*-gedit', 'mnuFile;mnuQuit')
```

It takes more than 30 sec to execute the line "ldtp.selectmenuitem ('*-gedit', 'mnuFile;mnuQuit')"

Comment: Are you sure that selectmenuitem(...) is taking time.

Answer (score 0):

I feel more time is taken during following lines.

```
from ldtp import *
from ldtputils import *
```

There are two ways to improve the performance;

1st : Don't use `from ldtp import *` instead use import `import ldtp`. You need to use ldtp.<> everytime.

2nd: If you are using only one function (say selectmenuitem) then use `from ldtp import selectmenuitem` at the top.